# How to handle AssertError in python

Tags: python, split, assert

I have a text string called newSong that contains two instancevariabel ( title, artist) like this:

```py
newSong = Song ("Rum and Raybans", "Sean Kingston and Cher Lloyd")
```

I have method called `checkIfArtistExists(self, artist)`. My task is to use split, for loop and if statements. I have to split artist, so if artist has name that consist of Sean, Kingston, Cher, Lloyd it would return true, else false.

I get assertError:

```py
>>> assert(not newSong.checkIfArtistExsists("Sadley"))       # False
AssertionError
```

Im new to programming and my logic aint that good... Could someone give me advice or tip?

```py
class Songs(object):

   def __init__(self, tittel, artist):

        #Instanse variabler

        self._tittel = tittel

        self._artist = artist

  def  CheckIfArtistExists(self,artist):


       names = artist.split()

       for n in names:
           if n in artist:
              return true
           else:
             return false

newSong = Song ("Rum and Raybans", "Sean Kingston and Cher Lloyd")

assert(newSong.CheckIfArtistExists("Sean Kingston and Cher Lloyd"))
assert(not newSong.CheckIfArtistExists(""Sadley"")) #False
```

Answer (score 0):

You are testing your `artist` argument against itself and not the instance variable `_artist`. This is why `newSong.checkIfArtistExists("Sadley")` is True when it should be False.

Your loop exits as soon as it finds a match. It should wait until it has tested all that are the split parts are substrings.

```
def CheckIfArtistExists(self, artist):

   names = artist.split()

   for n in names:
       if n not in self._artist:
          return False
   return True
```